# Delete products from single website

Tags: product, websites

I need to remove some of my products from one a single website and it's store view. How do I do this, without ending up deleting it from all all stores?

Answer (score 6):

The product-website association is kept in the table `catalog_product_website`.
If you have the product ids you can remove them fast from a specific website by running the query

```
DELETE FROM
    catalog_product_website
WHERE
    product_id IN (your product ids here separated by comma) AND
    website_id = website_id_here
```

When you are done, rebuild your indexes.

**[EDIT]**
If you don't want to touch the database you can do it via code like this:

```
$productIds = array(...your product ids here...);
$websiteId = your website id here
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->removeProducts(array($websiteId), $productIds);
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how the data profiles work (I've never used them) but I assume you don't get and id there because the id is not important for import /export functionality. but you should get an SKU. and from the SKU you can get the id like this `$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku)`.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it! :-) However, is this correct? `removeProducts(array($websiteId), $productIds);` Why would the websiteId be an array?

Comment: yes. It's correct. You can theoretically remove some products from more that 1 website at a time. And the method `removeProducts` expects the first parameter to be an array with 1 or more elements.  if you need a confirmation take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Website::removeProducts` and see how it works.